# How can I solve this limit?

Tags: trigonometry, limits

$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin (x-1)}{x-1}$

I know the answer equals $1$ because $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (x)}{x} = 1$ and in the following question $x-1$ gets arbitrary close to 0 so the same thing is happening. What I need is some steps to basically show that the question was not solved by a calculator.

I tried to use $\sin(A-B) = \sin A \mathrm{cos}B  - \sin B \cos A $ but I had a $\frac {0}0$ which is obviously wrong. Any help/tip would be great.

Comment: Maybe try using sin series expansion? Or L'Hospital

Comment: Try substitution $t=x-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply write down pretty much just what you’ve written here: it shows that you understand why the limit is $1$. However, a nice way is to make a substitution $y=x-1$; then clearly

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}=\lim_{y+1\to 1}\frac{\sin y}y=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}y=1\;.$$